# Azure cli virtual machine scale sets tutorial fails with "Parameter 'osProfile' is not allowed."?

Tags: azure-cli

Follwing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-custom-image-cli fails here with the error

```
...
$ az vmss create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myScaleSet --image /subscriptions/.../myGallery/images/myImageDefinition
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 6c5f031b-aa0e-42a8-a1d9-faba9b11b208. {
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "message": "Parameter 'osProfile' is not allowed.",
    "target": "osProfile"
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?  You can reproduce this easily using the script https://github.com/dankegel/azure-scripts/blob/main/ss-demo.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error with your script. The problem is that there is a missing "`\`" after the parameter `--image $IDID` in your script.

```
az vmss create \
   --resource-group myResourceGroup \
   --name myScaleSet \
   --image $IDID
   --specialized
```

It should be

```
az vmss create \
   --resource-group myResourceGroup \
   --name myScaleSet \
   --image $IDID \
   --specialized
```

Comment: Alas, that creates a generic vm, not one with the tutorial's customizations (in this case, nginx), doesn't it?

Comment: I found the problem, please check my update.

Comment: Yes, that's it, I found it independently.  But I appreciate the quick answer!